# JSONObjectRequest failing below API 28 using volley 1.1.1

Tags: android

JSONobjectrequest  works perfectly fine on API 28 but fails to respond below API 28 . Problem with volley? 
Tried this code on API 28 works just fine . but doesnt work below api 28 onerror response. URL is HTTPS so no issue on that front . Cleartext permitted included in manifest also just in case.

```
package com.ileap.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private static final String JSON_URL ="https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&from=2019-03-04&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=myAPI";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("response",response.toString());

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("error",error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

}


2019-04-04 07:12:41.972 6360-6360/com.ileap.test D/response: {"status":"ok","totalResults":6703,"articles":[{"source":{"id":null,"name":"Dailyfx.com"},"author":"David Cottle, Analyst, David Cottle","title":"Nikkei 225 Technical Analysis: Bulls Must Top March Peak Soon","description":"The Nikkei 225’s bounce endures but the bearish prospect of a ‘lower low’ has yet to be completely dealt with. This is now the bulls' first order of business","url":"https:\/\/www.dailyfx.com\/forex\/technical\/home\/analysis\/jpn225\/2019\/04\/04\/Nikkei-225-Technical-Analysisi-Bulls-Must-Top-March-Peak-Soon.html","urlToImage":null,"publishedAt":"2019-04-04T00:29:00Z",},"author":null,"title"


Result in API 28 but below that on API 23 and 21 no result . It doesn't connect to the URL at all and there is no error response either
```

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ileap.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "2.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: If i run emulators on API 28 I receive the JSON response as expected but if i run on API 23 or 21 in the emulator it just goes into loop or responds with onerror.  Tested on actual device same result . Anyone else facing this issue